# Creating and showing new Activity, can't use my fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

I've created a new `activity` and I'm showing it using an `intent`. In `onCreate` I'm trying to replace the placeholder fragment with my class but it's throwing an error - cannot resolve method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_viewer);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ViewerEditFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

ViewerEditFragment class:

```
public class ViewerEditFragment extends Fragment {

    public ViewerEditFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_viewer, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

activity_edit_viewer.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lightfootsolutions.sfnviewer.app.EditViewerActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

edit_viewer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit_viewer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sfn Credentials"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/username"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:hint="Admin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/entry"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:minWidth="100dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Host Settings"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/host_url"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hostUrl"
            android:hint="http://www.mysfn.com"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/web_app"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/webApp"
            android:hint="sfn"
            android:minWidth="100dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/model_id"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/modelId"
            android:hint="aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/properties"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/properties"
            android:hint="dv=icon"
            android:minWidth="100dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Save" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Good question is, what is in the activity_edit_viewer.xml and edit_viewer.xml. Also, refer to my post on Stack Overflow at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840509/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default-simple-fr for a simple fragment-based setup or Code Review at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default

Comment: What does your activity layout xml look like? Are you trying to replace a fragment element? If so, fragment elements in xml are not designed to be replaced like that. You need to specify a container for your Fragment, such as a `FrameLayout` element.

Comment: Do you extend Activity or FragmentActivity?

Comment: Be sure to extend FragmentActivity and make sure that all fragments extend the same Fragment class.  Meaning either the android support Fragment, or android.app.Fragment

Comment: @raz - Doesn't that depend on which version of android he is creating his app for? Higher versions don't require extending FragmentActivity.

Comment: Good point, if you're not using Support Fragments you don't need to extend it.  I just generally always use the Support Fragments so I forgot about that.

Comment: Updated question with xml. There is only one fragment i want displayed in this activity and it is the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` that I am importing. My `EditViewerActivity extends ActionBarActivity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're extending the android.support.v4.app.Fragment for your Fragment you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` rather than `getFragmentManager()`.  In this case be sure to `extend FragmentActivity`

Comment: +1 - Looks like they're extending `ActionBarActivity`, which should be fine.